# Rails: Is Better many small tables or one big table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller

In terms of performance, is it more efficient to use one large table as opposed to several smaller tables?

```
@animals = Animal.where(user_id: 1)
```

OR

```
@animals = Cat.where(user_id: 1) + Dog.where(user_id: 1)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: In general, one large table is better than many small tables:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273672/many-tables-or-rows-which-one-is-more-efficient-in-sql.

Comment: check about STI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you are questioning about (which can be applied to similar data modeling), one table would be better. The way I'd design the model `Animal` is for it to have an attribute `species` for example.

Getting all dogs and cats would simply be:

```
Animal.where("species = 'dog' OR species = 'cat'")
```

Or you can use the Rails 5 `or` method like so

```
Animal.where(species: 'dog').or(Animal.where(species: 'cat'))
```

Take a look at [Active Record query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)